# VBA Copyfile from and excel sheet : Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

Tags: vba, excel

[list file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwh9y.png)

i want to copyfile from a list in excel sheet  if there isn t any file their . But i have an error 5 in `fso.CopyFile filepath, Destination` . 
I do not know what is the problem , can you help me

```
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Destination = "C:\Users\test\"
Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(Destination)

Set workboo = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\listing.xlsx")
Set worksh = workboo.Worksheets("List_File")
For j = 1 To 10
    numrows = worksh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To numrows
            icol = 2 * j - 1
            filepath = worksh.Cells(i, icol).Value
            If Not fso.FileExists(Destination) Then
             fso.CopyFile filepath, Destination

            End If
        Next
Next

workboo.Close
    End Sub
```

Comment: You should debug for `filepath` values.

Comment: how is that ? because they are just paths of some files in excel sheet @Trimax

Comment: Can you upload either snapshot or sample file to sites like dropbox etc ,, to show how your files are listed in listing.xlsx file.

Comment: Are your files listed in columns A then Column C then Column E, because you loop in the code moves from 1st column to 3rd column while looping.

Comment: yes exactly ! they are in column A , C and E

Comment: @skkakkar i put a snapshot of the excel file

Comment: Is your directory path as shown in snapshot "P:\Desktop\Nouveau dosier(4)\Source\" will remain same or it can vary from cell to cell. If it remains same then perhaps dir path and file path can be seperated. Further more options to check file existence emerge if directorypath has to remain same.

Comment: @skkakkar yes it s the same directory i just need to move the files

Comment: I have got your concept and shall try to work it out but please have patience. In the meanwhile if someone gives a workable idea it is welcome.

Comment: @skkakkar i ll be so grateful .

Comment: Just to be sure, you have write access to the folder, aren't you?

Comment: if i understood your questin , i have acces to the folder

Comment: I have posted my answer. Hope it meets your requirements. If so, please do not forget to accept the answer by ticking green mark below bottom triangle on the left side of the answer. This is one thing which you can only do.

Comment: I have edited i and j figures in the program code.

Comment: I have edited a line regarding library reference also. Pl. go as per latest edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per information gathered from you, I have designed the program. I have kept source Folder and file string separately. To extract file name, I have used TRIM and MID functions.

```
 sFile = Trim(Mid((worksh.Cells(i, icol).Text), 39, 99))
```

You may check the length of the Source Folder "P:\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (4)\Source\" exactly by LEN function and then add 1 to that length for start of file name. Further I have kept total number of characters tentatively 99 which you may adjust according to maximum file name length you are using. Please also ensure that source and destination folders are correct in the program and match with your physical folder paths on your computer. I have tested it on my computer and it is working fine on sample data.I have also set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library.

```
Sub CopyingFiles_Q37539919()
    'Declaration
    Dim FSO
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sSFolder As String
    Dim sDFolder As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim numrows As Long

    Set workboo = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\listing.xlsx")
    Set worksh = workboo.Worksheets("List_File")
    numrows = worksh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print numrows

    'Change to match the source folder path.
    sSFolder = "C:\mydir_s\" '

    'Change to match the destination folder path.
    sDFolder = "C:\Users\test\"

    For j = 1 To 10
    For i = 2 To numrows
                icol = 2 * j - 1
        sFile = Trim(Mid((worksh.Cells(i, icol).Text), 39, 99)) ' Adjust the figure 39 for start of file name and 99 for maximum length of file name

        Debug.Print sFile
        Debug.Print sSFolder & sFile

        'Create Object for File System
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
         MsgBox "Specified File Not Found in Source Folder", vbInformation, "Not Found"
        End If

        'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
        If Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
        FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
        MsgBox "Specified File Copied to Destination Folder Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"

        Else
           MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"

        End If
    Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code expect `Destination` to be a file, but it is a directory. [FSO documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) tells you that:

> If source contains wildcard characters or destination ends with a path separator (), it is assumed that destination is an existing
>   folder in which to copy matching files. Otherwise, destination is
>   assumed to be the name of a file to create. In either case, three
>   things can happen when an individual file is copied.
>
> - If destination does not exist, source gets copied. This is the usual case.
> - If destination is an existing file, an error occurs if overwrite is False. Otherwise, an attempt is made to copy source over the
>     existing file.
> - If destination is a directory, an error occurs.

Make sure either `Destination`is set to a filename, not a directory, or that `filepath` is set to multiple files using wildcards.

BTW, if `Destination` is expected to remains a directory, you shouldn't test `fso.FileExists(Destination)`.

You can use `BuildPath()` and `GetFileName()` to construct the destination filename if needed:

```
Public Sub SomeName()
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Destination = "C:\Users\test\"
    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(Destination)

    Set workboo = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\listing.xlsx")
    Set worksh = workboo.Worksheets("List_File")
    For j = 1 To 10
        numrows = worksh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To numrows
            icol = 2 * j - 1
            filepath = worksh.Cells(i, icol).Value
            filedest = fso.BuildPath(Destination,fso.GetFileName(filepath))
            If Not fso.FileExists(filedest) Then
                fso.CopyFile filepath, filedest
            End If
        Next
    Next
    workboo.Close
End Sub
```

I didn't edit much your code, but defining you variable with `Dim ...` should be a good idea.

Comment: Appreciate for explaining the concepts involved nicely.

Comment: in fact , the destination is a directory , and i want to check if file exist on it . I edited the code but still the problem in the copyfile line . otherwise , the filepath is a path of the file , the source is fine and the files exists .. @skkakkar

Comment: Could you give us the values of filepath and filedest when the code fails?

Comment: @VincentG the files moves to the destination but the window of error is still appearing each time i execute the code . I tried to put " on error resume next " but then the files don t move

Answer (score 0):

On seeing your code i agree with Trimax the area of problem he is pointing. Apart from that you need to make sure followings:
1. Make sure "filepath" variable is fully qualified path for the file like "d:\yourdirctoryname\yourfilename.extension"
2. Make sure file exists at source location if not the same validation you can write for "filepath" as you did for "destination"
3. if you have same extension files to be copied then you should use wildcard to copy file to the destination it will reduce system effort. For more detail follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w(v=vs.84).aspx for wildcard code.

I believe it will resolve the issue.

Comment: in fact i should open the list in excel and move file from it . i checked the path it is the full path of the file so there is not a problem in that. and it s not working